# Warning: urlencode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /wp-includes/formatting.php on line 5343

Tags: php

Anyone can help me about that? Code on line 5343 is:

```php
    return urldecode( basename( str_replace( array( '%2F', '%5C' ), '/',
```

Comment: Your code block has been cut off so there is no `urlencode` in your question, which function is this inside? And where does the warning occur? Frontend? Backend? AJAX? CLI? On some pages? All pages?

Comment: Hi Tom , thanks for helping , Its a search box about realestate website and it is showned on Frontend when people try to search propperties

Comment: function wp_basename( $path, $suffix = '' ) {
 return urldecode( basename( str_replace( array( '%2F', '%5C' ), '/', urlencode( $path ) ), $suffix ) );
}

Comment: Ah ok, so somebody somewhere called `wp_basename` and passed an array instead of a string, now you need to figure out where that happened. Debugging tools such as stack traces will help you show what called that function incorrectly, such as xdebug, or plugins such as query monitor. Just know that you have yet to find the actual problem code, your debugging is unfinished